# What is the Time Complexity of CvSVM::train_auto in multi-class task according to its parameters in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, multilabel-classification

What is the Time Complexity of **CvSVM::train_auto** in **OpenCV** according to its parameters?

Particularly,

- the BOW (Bag-of-words) vocabulary size
- amount of classes
- amount of samples

for training.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: 42 - Why not do your own homework

Comment: @EdHeal : Actually I have done a lot of homework on the official document, but still can't fig it out ...  I have written a  multi-class (over 400 classes) classification program using CvSVM+BOW according to its sample code in the library, with the vocabulary size 10000, about 17000 training images. The program has been running for 6 days on the training stage and don't know when will finish. If you know something about this, can you give me some clues to start?

Comment: URL to that document please

Comment: @EdHeal: Thank you in advance! http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/object_categorization.html?highlight=bagofwords_classification